# How to implement the EasyQuery in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, web-applications

The shortest way to ad-hoc reporting is EasyQuery

Most of database applications contain some functionality for searching and filtration. But it is impossible to foresee all possible types of queries the users of your application will need to build.

Can any one explain me how to implement easy query in my .Net web app?

Comment: Given this is a paid for solution I'd suggest you contact the support team or look on : http://devtools.korzh.com/kb/?p=EQN.WEB

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of implementations for both asp.net webforms and mvc when you download and install the product. I'm currently going through their MVC project and seeing what's what myself.